# Postgres: best solution to ignore errors during bulk insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've seen bunch of similar questions here. But my question, i guess, specific.

This is best solution i've found for current version of Postgres (9.4):
http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE

Generally, the suggested solution is based on algorithm: insert one row, if error happened - do something, if not - insert next one.

If all i need is to ignore duplicate errors, can I just do this?

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,surname) values (1,'john','doe')
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,surname) values (2,'jane','smith')
```

instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,surname) values (1,'john','doe'),(2,'jane','smith')
```

...if I have to insert only ~5-30 rows at once?
so, some of inserted rows just return duplicate errors, but the rest of them will be executed successfully. This is all I need, actually.

I've tried to compare the cost of those approaches by `EXPLAIN INSERT` 100 rows at once and 100 rows separately. Probably, I'm doing something wrong, because it shows ~25-50 times lesser execution time, when I'm inserting rows **separately**, like in first example:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,surname) values (1,'john','doe')
INSERT INTO tablename (id,name,surname) values (2,'jane','smith')
```

Here is query wrapper i was using:

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
-- query or queriES here
ROLLBACK;
```

So, the question is, why am I receiving this? May be, `EXPLAIN` shows execution time for each row instead of the whole query? Then it makes sense: in this case, bulk insert will cost ~3 times less than separated commands. Right?

Comment: If you choose _not_ to go with bulk insert, is your business logic prepared to handle the situation where, say half, of your records were inserted but the other half were not?

Comment: absolutely! if it will not make the query execution time, say, 50 times longer, then separate inserting is exactly what i need

Comment: So you are saying that execution time took 25-50 times less for say 100 insertions separately versus 100 in bulk?

Comment: I think, my results are wrong, because it's illogical. Could you try this yourself? It should not take more than few minutes

Comment: I can't account for your `EXPLAIN` results, but you probably don't want to be doing individual inserts in any case, q.v. [this Stack Exchange DBA article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63055/increased-performance-from-single-statement-multiple-row-inserts).

Comment: by separated inserts i mean bunch of `INSERT` queries within a single transaction: `BEGIN - COMMIT`, or in the example above `BEGIN - ROLLBACK`. So, as i've just read here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html , this is acceptable solution. Unfortunately, there are no actual performanse-related numbers in the article. Could you try to use `BEGIN EXPLAIN ANALIZE ... ROLLBACK` to compare bulk and row-by-row within a single transaction approaches?

Comment: I think you might be using `EXPLAIN` wrongly.  But can you try doing a 100 bulk insert, rollback, then insert 100 records one at a time?  Compare the actual execution times of both.

Comment: I've just did exactly what you've mentioned and explained it in the initial question description.  
Sorry, probably i've explained this not clear enough, because my english is not perfect)

Comment: 9.5 will have `insert .. on conflict do nothing` which can be combined with multi-row inserts. It's currently available as a release candidate with the final release to be expected in January 2016

Answer (score 2):

```
with i (id, name, surname) as (values (1,'john','doe'),(2,'jane','smith'))
insert into t (id, name, surname)
select id, name, surname
from i
where not exists (
   select 1
   from t
   where id = i.id and name = i.name and surname = i.surname
)
```

There is a race condition above if data can be inserted in any other way. Just retry if an error occurs.

Comment: you are suggesting to make two more selects per each insert. I'm almost sure this costs much more, than just inserts without selects)

Comment: @stkvtflw: "two more selects per insert" : you are wrong, the above query is effectively one statement, and probably the most efficient. (BTW: there is no need to care about efficiency when inserting only a couple of rows)